# How to conduct user testing to identify the optimal position for an entry point of a feature

Tags: user-research, user-journey

I'm conducting a user testing session to identify what is the optimal entry point on a flight booking mobile app, to introduce users to its frequent flyer program.

Potential entry points are

- after booking of flight tickets
- before check-in
- on the home screen
- other suggestions by the user

the design itself is a static component with some copy and a 'register now' button.

This question is not looking for the answer of which is the optimal entry point, but more regarding what kind of a test should be presented to the participant. Normally user tests are conducted to get feedback on a particular feature. however, the aim of this is to identify the best place in the app (and users journey) to include an entry point to sign up.

Would appreciate suggestions and feedback on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably two different questions actually. (1) Where do users *expect* that feature to be and (2) where would the feature *perform best in normal use*. It might be that (1) is different from (2), but you'd probably need to explore that in a live split test.

To answer the first question in a usability test, you could ask the participant to find details of the frequent flyer program (or sign up for the program depending on the feature that you want to test). Observe where they look for it and then watch for patterns when comparing participants.

Depending on how many participants you have and how easy it is to move that feature from one place to another, you could try to answer (2) by performing a quick and dirty split test. Prototype a few versions with the feature in different places. See which one performs best.